# Magento 2 unable to send eMail, exeption error

Tags: magento2, error, email

- I got this error message in my exception file.

  ```
  First Name :test<br>2 exception(s):
  Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException): Unable to send mail. 
  Exception #1 (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception): Unable to send mail. 



  <?php
  /**
  *
  * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
  namespace vendorname\modulename\Controller\Index;


  use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
  use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

  class Index extends Action
  {
   private $dataPersistor;
  /**
   * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
   */

  protected $context;



  /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
   */
  protected $_transportBuilder;

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
   */
  protected $inlineTranslation;

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
   */
  protected $scopeConfig;

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
   */


  /**
   * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
   * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
   */

   public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
      \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
      \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
      \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
  ) {
      parent::__construct($context,$transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig );
      $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
      $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
  }

  public function execute()
  {
      $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($post);
      echo "</pre>"; 

      $txt='';

      if($post['fname']){         
          $txt.='Client Name :'.$post['fname'].'<br>';            
      }
      if($post['address']){           
          $txt.='Address :'.$post['address'].'<br>';          
      }
      if($post['city']){
          $txt.='City :'.$post['city'].'<br>';
      }
      if($post['state']){
          $txt.='State/Province :'.$post['state'].'<br>';
      }
      if($post['zipcode']){
          $txt.='Zip Code :'.$post['zipcode'].'<br>';
      }
      if($post['phone']){
          $txt.='Phone :'.$post['phone'].'<br>';
      }
      if($post['email']){
          $txt.='Email :'.$post['email'].'<br>';
      }
      if(!empty($post['project_type'])){      
          $projecttypearray = implode(",",$post['project_type']);     
          $txt.='Project Type :'.$projecttypearray.'<br>';            
      }

      if($post['comment']){
          $txt.='Comment :'.$post['comment'].'<br>';
      }
      echo $txt;


      $customerName=$post['fname'];
      $message=$txt;
      $userSubject='test mail';

      $fromEmail='admin@gmail';
      $fromName ='test name';

       $templateVars = [
                  'store' => 1,
                  'customer_name' => $customerName,
                  'subject' => $userSubject,
                  'message'   => $message
              ];
      $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
      $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
      $to = 'test@gmail.com';

      $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

       $templateOptions = [
        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
        'store' => 1
      ];

      $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(1, $storeScope)
              ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
              ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
              ->setFrom($from)
              ->addTo($to)               
              ->getTransport();
      $transport->sendMessage();
      $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;


class Index extends Action
{
    private $dataPersistor;
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */

    protected $context;



    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Modia\Cform\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig );
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        $txt='<table>';

        if($post['fname']){         
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Client Name</strong>:'.$post['fname'].'</td></tr>';          
        }
        if($post['address']){           
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Address</strong>:'.$post['address'].'</td></tr>';            
        }
        if($post['city']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>City</strong>:'.$post['city'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['state']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>State/Province</strong>:'.$post['state'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['zipcode']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Zip Code</strong>:'.$post['zipcode'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['phone']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Phone</strong>:'.$post['phone'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['email']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Email</strong>:'.$post['email'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if(!empty($post['project_type'])){      
            $projecttypearray = implode(",",$post['project_type']);     
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Project Type</strong>:'.$projecttypearray.'</td></tr>';          
        }

        if($post['comment']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        $txt.='</table>';
        //echo $txt;



        $customerName='Test Form';
        $message=$txt;

        $userSubject= 'Demo From ';     
        $fromEmail= 'admin@gmail.com.com';
        $fromName = 'Demo Form';

         $templateVars = [
                    'store' => 1,
                    'customer_name' => $customerName,
                    'subject' => $userSubject,
                    'message'   => $message
                ];
        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();


        $to = 'test@gmail.com';     

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

         $templateOptions = [
          'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
          'store' => 1
        ];

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(5, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)               
                ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

        $this->_redirect('form');
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your controller

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        return parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $senderEmail = "sender_address@example.com";
        $senderName = "Sender Name";
        $recipientEmail = "receivers_address@example.com";

        $identifier = 1;  // Enter your email template identifier here

        $requestData = array();

        if($post['fname']){
            $requestData['fname'] = $post['fname'];
        }
        if($post['address']){
            $requestData['address'] = $post['address'];
        }
        if($post['city']){
            $requestData['city'] = $post['city'];
        }
        if($post['state']){
            $requestData['state'] = $post['state'];
        }
        // You can add more data as given above

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($requestData);

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($identifier)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom(['name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail])
            ->addTo([$recipientEmail])
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

    }
}
```

Add below variables in your email template.

```
{{depend data.fname}}
{{trans "First Name: %fname" fname=$data.fname}}<br/>
{{/depend}}

{{depend data.address}}
{{trans "Address: %address" address=$data.address}}<br/>
{{/depend}}

{{depend data.city}}
{{trans "City: %city" city=$data.city}}<br/>
{{/depend}}

{{depend data.state}}
{{trans "State: %state" state=$data.state}}<br/>
{{/depend}}
```